# When overriding Object.Equals, is it appropriate to use the passed in object's Equals(MyType)?

Tags: c#, iequatable

For a simple example, assume you have two classes that are different in many ways, but can still be considered "equateable":

```
class WholeNumber: IEquatable<WholeNumber> {
    int value;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj is IEquatable<WholeNumber>) {
            IEquatable<WholeNumber> other = (IEquatable<WholeNumber>) obj;
            return other.Equals(this);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(WholeNumber other) {
        return this.value == other.value;
    }
}

class Fraction : IEquatable<WholeNumber> {
    WholeNumber numerator;
    WholeNumber denominator;

    public bool Equals(WholeNumber other) {
        if (denominator != 1) {
            // Assume fraction is already reduced
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.numerator.Equals(other);
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow any object that claims to be equateable to WholeNumber to be passed into the WholeNumber's Equals(object) function and get the desired result without WholeNumber needed to know about any other class.

Is this pattern a good idea? Is using IEquatable with other classes a common (where it makes sence) thing to do?

Comment: Please do the appropriate null checks in the code, and also your recursion checks ;)

Comment: Why not create a class called Number and have the two classes derive from that? Then you can have Number implement IEquatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is a bad idea.  While infinite recursion does not happen with this code, it is a constant threat when you have some instances of `Equals()` delegating to others.  (If you use this approach then I'd strongly suggest writing many unit tests to make sure that `Equals()` does what you expect in all cases.)

Note that when `a.Equals((object)b)` returns true, `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()` must also be true.  If you cannot ensure that `new WholeNumber(2)` and `new Fraction(2, 4)` have the same hash code, then **they should not compare as equal by `Equals(object)`**.

The practice I have adopted is that the `Equals(object)` override only returns true if the argument's type is or derives from the type where the override is declared -- in this case, `obj is WholeNumber`.  If this is true but `obj.GetType() != typeof(WholeNumber)` then I do call `b.Equals(a)` so that the more-derived `Equals()` gets priority.

If you need equality with cousin types, then that is where `IEquatable<T>` comes in.  In this case you would implement `IEquatable<Fraction>` on `WholeNumber` too, and it would make perfect sense to delegate to `Fraction`'s implementation of `IEquatable<WholeNumber>.Equals()` to avoid duplicating that logic.  (Providing an implicit conversion from `WholeNumber` to `Fraction` might be beneficial here, too.)

Comment: Wait, obj is being cast to an IEquateable<WholeNumber> and `this` is a `WholeNumber` so the `Equals(WholeNumber)` should be used.

Comment: Yeah, overload resolution saves you here and you don't get infinite recursion.  Nevertheless I agree that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Cemafor Ah, I see you are right about that. I will amend the answer.

Comment: I get what you are saying about only returning true if the object is of a derived type, but it seems weird that if A inherits from B than `a.Equals(b)` may not equal `b.Equals(a)`

Comment: @Cemafor Yes, my wording in that part is not very clear and doesn't really give the meaning that I intended.  I will try to rework that section.